# What bootstrap component should I use?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to make a simple 6 page website. Here's the code of my main page so far

```
<hmtl>
<style>
    .ali{
        width:170px;
        text-align:center;
    }
footer{
  background:#333;
  color:#eee;
  font-size:11px;
  padding-top: 25px;
 padding-bottom: 25px;
 text-align:center;

}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <div class="container" id="main">
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="ali"><a href="page1.html">Page 1</a></li>
                <li class="ali"><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                <li class="ali"><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
                <li class="ali"><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
                <li class="ali"><a href="#">Page 5</a></li>
                <li class="ali"><a href="#">Page 6</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">   
                    <img src="http://cdn.desktopwallpapers4.me/wallpapers/photography/1920x1080/3/24275-world-through-a-lens-1920x1080-photography-wallpaper.jpg" alt="Lens">
                </div>

                <div class="item">
        <img src="http://newartcolorz.com/images/lens-wallpaper/kartandtinki1_lens-wallpaper_03.jpg" alt="lesis">
            </div>
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>  <!-- end of carousel inner -->
    </div> <!-- end of carousel -->
    <footer>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <hr></hr>
            <h6>Copyright &copy; 2015 {Author}</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Im using navbar as a navigation between web pages. But what I want to do is to replace only the carousel part of the document with the new page when the navbar is clicked. But right now on a press it completely reloads a new page which is what I dont want to do. How can I do this,what I need to change, should I use bootstrap tabs instead of  navbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [Tab](http://v3.bootcss.com/javascript/#tabs), in your case, put your content of the 6 pages in different tab divs, and let Bootstrap to do the magic. However, I think essentially, what you want is 6 different pages with the same navigation bar. This kind of functionality is not covered by Bootstrap. You may want to use some framework, for example [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/)(create customised directive or simply use ng-include directive), to do this.

Comment: Thanks. Its for my school and I dont want to waste a lot of time on it. If I use angular it will be too advanced and the teacher will not understand the code, but yes with angular it would become like an SPA changing the `ng-view`.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent reload of the document you would need to use bootstrap [Togglable tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs)